# Qt 5.11 - Embed external application into QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i'm trying to make an qt MainWindow application that show in QWidget ( ui->appWidget ) an external window (other app that i run from a QProcess ).

Now , when i do so , the new widget get the ui->appWidget size ,
but it doesn't get into it , it still show the external app as an external window.

What i need to do to make it be embedded into the ui->appWidget ?

**this is my code :**

```
void MainWindow::runScript(QString command){

    //Set Procees to Scripts directory
    process.setWorkingDirectory(directory.currentPath() + "/Scripts");

    //Open command process
    process.start("./" + command + ".sh" );

    //Check if Script succeed to open
    if(process.waitForStarted() == false){
        qDebug() << "Error starting " << command << " Script";
        qDebug() << "ERROR: " << process.errorString();
   }else{
        qDebug() << "Script succeed to open";
    }


    QThread::msleep(5000); // make sure process is up.

    QWindow * window =  QWindow::fromWinId(0x3200005); // 0x3200005 - Hardcoded window id .
    QWidget * widget = createWindowContainer(window);
    QVBoxLayout * vl = new QVBoxLayout(ui->appWidget);
    vl->addWidget(widget);
    ui->appWidget->setLayout(vl);
    widget->show();

}
```

If more details are needed please tell me .

Thanks for the help !

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are setting the layout to the wrong widget.

Take a look at this piece of code, it moves an existing window (dolphin file manager - I retrieved the window id through the xwininfo command) inside a QMainWindow:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int l_result = -1;

    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QMainWindow* l_main_win = new QMainWindow();
    l_main_win->setWindowTitle("DOLPHIN EMBEDDED IN QT APPLICATION!");

    QWindow *l_container = QWindow::fromWinId(0x4400005);
    QWidget *l_widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(l_container);

    l_main_win->setCentralWidget(l_widget);
    l_main_win->show();

    l_result = app.exec();

    return l_result;
}
```

and it moves my dolphin window inside a Qt main window named "DOLPHIN EMBEDDED IN QT APPLICATION!":

[image]