# Unembedding application from QWidget

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608457/qt-5-11-embed-external-application-into-qwidget).
After embedding an external application with the code:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include<QProcess>
#include<QDesktopServices>
#include<QUrl>
#include<QWindow>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow();
    w->setWindowTitle("Genome Embedded Calculator");
    QWindow* window = QWindow::fromWinId(41943047); // Hardcoded Window Id for Genome Calculator
    window->setFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
    w->setCentralWidget(widget);
    w->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

How to detach the `QWindow` after closing the application?
I want the `gnome-calculator` process to continue working after closing my application.

Comment: Does calling `QWindow::setParent(nullptr)` solves your problem?

Comment: @Belal, did the suggestion from m7913d solved your issue ?

Comment: @m7913d No it does not solve it. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I hadn't the time to try it myself (so I left a comment instead of an answer). It was the way I would expect it to work.